# Issue in installing MS Service Fabric SDK 3.2.162

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Error while installation of MS Service Fabric SDK 3.2.162.

### MS Azure Service Fabric Runtime 6.3.162 Fails to install.

```
Partial Log File ....
```

DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ignoring exit code '0' for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162'. Commandline is: 'C:\WINDOWS\sysnative\cmd.exe /c sc.exe stop KtlLogger'. Process Id: 12956
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162' is '1060'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ignoring exit code '1060' for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162'. Commandline is: 'C:\WINDOWS\sysnative\cmd.exe /c sc.exe stop LeasLayr'. Process Id: 7372
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162' is '1060'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ignoring exit code '1060' for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\rajesh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\ServiceFabricRuntime_6_3_RTO\A2934A42C9B2607C258C14DD52DBE267EF254827\MicrosoftServiceFabric.6.3.162.9494.exe /AcceptEULA'. Process Id: 8604
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162' is '1'
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162' is FailureDownloadManager Information: 0 : Ignoring exit code '0' for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162'. Commandline is: 'C:\WINDOWS\sysnative\cmd.exe /c sc.exe stop KtlLogger'. Process Id: 12956
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162' is '1060'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ignoring exit code '1060' for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162'. Commandline is: 'C:\WINDOWS\sysnative\cmd.exe /c sc.exe stop LeasLayr'. Process Id: 7372
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162' is '1060'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ignoring exit code '1060' for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\rajesh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\ServiceFabricRuntime_6_3_RTO\A2934A42C9B2607C258C14DD52DBE267EF254827\MicrosoftServiceFabric.6.3.162.9494.exe /AcceptEULA'. Process Id: 8604
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162' is '1'
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime - 6.3.162' is Failure

**system details**

OS Windows 10 Home  Version 1808 (64 Bit). Hardware I7 with 8 GB RAM.
Visual studio Community Edition installed.
Web Platform Installer 5.0 Installed.
PowerShell Version     5.1.17134.165 (powershell path is already added to path variable)

(**Other investigation details...
MicrosoftServiceFabric.6.3.162.9494.exe /AcceptEULA fails**

Log details below
C:\Users\rajesh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WEBPLA~1\installers\ServiceFabricRuntime_6_3_RTO\A2934A42C9B2607C258C14DD52DBE267EF254827>MicrosoftServiceFabric.6.3.162.9494.exe /AcceptEULA
09/08/2018 19:06:42,Info,Start installation... Logs created at C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\InstallFabricRuntime.log
09/08/2018 19:06:42,Info,10/08/2018 00:36:42 running: Powershell.exe -NoProfile Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser
09/08/2018 19:06:42,Info,Service Fabric Product not detected in registry.
09/08/2018 19:06:42,Info,Found legacy fabric files at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric. Start removal...
09/08/2018 19:06:42,Info,10/08/2018 00:36:42 running: Powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\CleanFabric.ps1'
09/08/2018 19:06:45,Info,Legacy Fabric Uninstalled using CleanFabric.ps1!
09/08/2018 19:06:45,Info,Start extracting runtime cab...
09/08/2018 19:06:47,Info,10/08/2018 00:36:47 running: C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\MicrosoftServiceFabricAutoextractor.exe /L "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric" /E /Y
09/08/2018 19:07:00,Info,Successfully extracted cab file
09/08/2018 19:07:00,Info,Start installing...
09/08/2018 19:07:00,Info,10/08/2018 00:37:00 running: Powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command & 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\InstallFabric.ps1' -FabricRootIsPreInstalled -ACCEPTEULA
09/08/2018 19:07:11,Error,Unable to install Service Fabric Runtime using InstallFabric.ps1. ExitCode: 1

)

Comment: Dumping an error log here without any description of your problem and the attempted solutions won't make you life any easier.

Comment: It is installation error while installing MS Service Fabric SDK. Please check all investigation details are already provided. Let me know if any additional details are required.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to enable execution of the Windows PowerShell scripts included in the SDK. For more information about how to install Service Fabric SDK 3.2.162, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started).

> Service Fabric uses Windows PowerShell scripts for creating a local development cluster and for deploying applications from Visual Studio. By default, Windows blocks these scripts from running. To enable them, you must modify your PowerShell execution policy. Open PowerShell as an administrator and enter the following command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser
```

I can install [Service Fabric SDK 3.2.162](http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK) on my side.

[image]

If it also can't be installed. You also could try to do it with [other ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started#install-the-sdk-and-tools):

> - [To use Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started#to-use-visual-studio-2017)
> - [To use Visual Studio 2015 (requires Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 or later)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started#to-use-visual-studio-2017)